# File encryption in php - algorithm

Tags: php, encryption

What is the algorithm according to you is best to encrypt files using PHP?
Maximum file size which provides about 100 mb.
I care about the speed of the encryption ...

Comment: ending a SO question with elipses is probably the first wrong part...

Comment: this needs to be closed as its subjective

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php
will explain better..